# Iteratively replace two strings with values from numpy array

Tags: python, regex, numpy, replace, iteration

I'm currently trying to make an automation script for writing new files from a master where there are two strings I want to replace (x1 and x2) with values from a 21 x 2 array of numbers (namely, [[0,1000],[50,950],[100,900],...,[1000,0]]). Additionally, with each double replacement, I want to save that change as a unique file.

Here's my script as it stands:

```
import numpy
lines = []
x1x2 = numpy.array([[0,1000],[50,950],[100,900],...,[1000,0])
for i,j in x1x2:
with open("filenamexx.inp") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        linex1 = line.replace('x1',str(i))
        linex2 = line.replace('x2',str(j))
        lines.append(linex1)
        lines.append(linex2)
with open("filename"+str(i)+str(j)+".inp", 'w') as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line)
```

With my current script there are a few problems. First, the string replacements are being done separately, i.e. I end up with a new file that contains the contents of the master file twice where one line has the first change and then the next will reflect the second separately. Second, with each subsequent iteration, the new files have the contents of the previous file prepended (i.e. filename100900.inp will contain its unique contents as well as the contents of both filename01000.inp and filename50950.inp before it). Anyone think they can take a crack at solving my problem?

Note: I've looked at using regex module solutions (somehing like this: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-2nd/0596007973/ch01s19.html) in order to do multiple replacements in a single pass, but I'm not sure if the way I'm indexing is translatable to a dictionary object.

Comment: Note: Thank you so much armatita; it works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the second issue but you can use replace more than one time on the same string, so:

```
     s = "x1 stuff x2"
     s = s.replace('x1',str(1)).replace('x2',str(2))
     print(s)
```

, will output:

```
     1 stuff 2
```

No need to do this two times for two different variables. As for the second issue it just seems as your not "reset-ing" the "lines" variable before starting to write a new file. So once you finish writing a file just add:

```
     lines = []
```

It should be enough to solve these issues.